# Enable/Disable mobile data

Tags: android, time, data-connections

I am trying to enable/disable mobile data at particular time of the day. After googling through all the stuff this is what I have:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ....
 onCreate{ blah blah
 }

 public void onToggleClicked(View v) {
          Calendar objCal = Calendar.getInstance();

      objCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); 
              objCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      objCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
              PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent( context,
      MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
              AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, objCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

     //if condition here

      try { 

     Network objNetwork = new Network();
     objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(getBaseContext(), true); // set to false at x:00 pm

      } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

Current Error: context cannot be resolved to a variable.

I am new to android dev and am not really sure if all this is correct...
I havent created an intent specifically...

Comment: Can you post the class in which you are using this?

Comment: you are probably defined the `context` variable in a scope that is outside of the current one.

Comment: ohh, this is the whole class... Well, replace `context` with `this` then...

Comment: Try adding all this code in the `onCreate` method and replace context with "this"

Comment: I havent defined the context variable at all... Where do I define it? What does it mean?

Comment: I am able to achieve it on click of a toggle button... its just that I need it to work at a particular time without having to click any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity` is instance of `Context`. Use `this` instead of `context`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import android.content.Context
```

to the top of your activity sourcecode

Comment: add this line to the oncreate 'Context context = getContext;'